# How to limit Bootstrap 4 column height to another columns height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have two columns in a row. The left columns has a fixed height given by the content it holds `height:auto`. The right column is longer than the left column. **How can I overflow the right column once it reaches the height of the left column?**

I already tried to give the right column `overflow-y: scroll; max-height: 200px;`. But I want the right column to automatically adjust to the left column, without specifying a length-based height.

[Here is my current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeSC1.png)

I also created a JSFiddle with my problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/f2ywt8o1/1/).

I am using Bootstrap 4.6.0 in my Angular project.

My HTML code currently looks like this:

```
 <div class="row justify-content-center">    
    <div class="col">    
        <mat-list role="list">
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">STATUS: {{statusText}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">UserId: {{character?.userId}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">CharacterId: {{character?._id}}</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Gender: {{character?.gender}}</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Region Id: {{character?.regionId}} </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">
                Region name: {{region?.name}} 
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" [routerLink]="['/regions', character?.regionId]">Overview</button>
                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="goToMap(character?.regionId)">Show on Worldmap</button>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">City Id: {{character?.cityId}} </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">City name: {{city?.name}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">HP: {{character?.hp}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Strength: {{character?.strength}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Agility: {{character?.agility}}</mat-list-item>   
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Intelligence: {{character?.intelligence}}</mat-list-item>   
        </mat-list>
    </div>
    <div class="col"> 
        <div class="row limit">
            <mat-card *ngFor="let log of logs" style="margin-top:10px; width:100%">
                <div class="row">
                        <mat-card-header>
                            <mat-card-title>{{log.action}}</mat-card-title>
                            <mat-card-subtitle>{{log.objectId}}</mat-card-subtitle>
                        </mat-card-header>
                </div>
            </mat-card>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="logsCurrentPage > 1" class="row justify-content-center">
            <button class='btn-margin' mat-raised-button color="secondary" (click)='loadNextLogPage()'>Load more</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that a pure css method is possible here. You can do this quite simply using Javascript. Just get the height of the left column and set the right column to it's height.

Working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/036v75ap/6/

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">    
        <div class="col" id="left-col" style="background-color:blue">    
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="right-col" style="background-color:red"> 
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
#left-col {
  height: fit-content;
}
#right-col {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let height = $('#left-col').css('height');
  $('#right-col').css('height', height);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the right column to dynamically have the same height as the left column, then you probably thinking use some JS or JQuery help.

See the snippet below:

```js
var leftHeight = document.getElementById('left-col').clientHeight;
document.getElementById('right-col').style.height = leftHeight + 'px';
```

```css
#right-col {
  overflow: scroll;
}
.col {
    height: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">    
        <div class="col" id="left-col" style="background-color:blue">    
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
          <p>some content in the left column</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="right-col" style="background-color:red"> 
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p>some content in the right column</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
          <p style="background-color:green">this should be in the overflow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your solution uses a predefined height for the parent row. But I want to limit the height of the right column, based on its "siblings" column height. The height of the left column should be based on the content it holds (height:auto).

Comment: "Height" value is hard to control using CSS since different browsers and different resolutions, so using JS or JQuery functions will get you the dynamic height property. If you would like the sibilings to have something like "different text color or background color", you can try  [CSS Combinators](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)